# use jquery $(document).on() to delegate error event to IMG

Tags: javascript, jquery

We can use `$(document).on('event', 'selector', function)` to delegate events for every element matched by `selector`.

But the same logic seems not working when I'm trying to delegate `error`.

```
    $(document).on('error', 'img', function () {
        console.log(1); // not working
    });
    $('img').bind('error', function(){        
        console.log(2); // working
    }); 
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('img').on('error', function(){
           console.log(3); // working
        });
    });
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/9urqfnjg/2/)

How can I delegate `error` event then?

Comment: The [error event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/error) does not bubble so you can't use it for delegated handlers

Comment: `$('img').on('error', ...)` works though.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly Yes but I cannot delegate it to 'selector' instead an object

Comment: @ArunPJohny I wish your comment was the accepted answer.